# why two date classes one in java.util.Date and java.sql.Date?

Tags: java

HI
I like to know why there are two Date classes in two different packages one in `java.util.Date` and one in `java.sql.Date`?
Whats the use of having two Date classes?

Comment: Somtimes I think to make programmers life harder

Comment: And then there's JODA...

Comment: But you skipped over `java.util.Calendar`!  Ironically, there's not a single one of these (JDK classes) that you should ever actually use (unless forced). Joda-Time is the only date/time API done right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`java.util.Date` is Java's Date data type.

`java.sql.Date` is a JDBC wrapper for SQL dates.

<strike>The two are represented completely differently internally.</strike>

.NET has the same concepts (but a better naming convention to differentiate the two in my opinion) with `System.DataTime` and `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime`

Answer (score 3):

[java.sql.Date](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

> A thin wrapper around a millisecond value ***that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value***. A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT.

Answer (score 3):

The `java.sql.Date` is a subclass (an extension) of `java.util.Date`.
What changed in `java.sql.Date`:

1. `toString()` generates a different string representation: `yyyy-mm-dd`
2. a static `valueOf(String)` methods to create a Date from a String with above representation
3. the getters and setter for hours, minutes and seconds are deprecated

The `java.sql.Date` class is used with JDBC and it was intended to not have a time part, that is, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds should be zero... but this is not *enforced* by the class.